# Mikrotik RouterOS FTP protocol routing

Tags: networking, ftp, port, mikrotik-routeros

I have Routerboard 951Ui-2HnD and I am using it to merge/combine two internet lines `wan1` and `wan2` and it's working fine but I am facing a problem when I am trying to connect to any `FTP` server or cPanel ( i am a web developer ) because of the 2 IPs it's forces me to logout every 15 seconds as security measure.

I need to force any FTP ( port `21` ) connection to be using a single `wan` ( let's say `wan1` ) and some wild card websites to do the same. for example I want any `SSL` ( port `443` ) connection to *.siteground.com use single wan also.

I hope I explained the problem correctly as I searched for days and I can't find anything ... and I assume I am searching wrong.

Thanks for your time guys.
Regards,
Nabeel